# Generate HTML file with both quote ' and " from R

Tags: html, r

I need to create an HTML file from R software. The problem is that javascript implies simple quote and styles double quote in the string generated.

cat() function returns a quite good text removing backslashs in front of ". But I did not found how to print it like this in an html file using  write.table(Text, "index.html", sep="\t")

Thanks in advance for any help.

NB : I removed a "<" character in front of /script in order to be able to post it =)

For exemple :

```
Text=paste0('<html> 
               <script type="text/javascript">',
               "function lang1(event) {
              var iframe = document.getElementById('id1');
               var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
                iframe.src = event.target.innerHTML + '.html';
                }
             /script>",
              '<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
              <div id="main">
                <div id="content">
               <table style="border: 0; height:100%;width:100%;">
               <tr style="height:5%;">
               <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
               <h2>',paste0("some text"),'</h2> 
             </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%;font-size:14px;">
                <ul onclick="lang1(event);">',
               paste('<li>',c("link1","link2"),'</li>',collapse=""),
              '</ul>
               </td>
                <td style="width: 90%;"> 
               <iframe id="id1" width="99%" height="99%"></iframe>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
               </div>
              </body>
              </html>')
   Text=gsub("\n","",Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but whenever I generate html files from text in R, I use the \ character to escape quote marks that are needed in the JavaScript. 
Then I open a file connection and use the writeLines function to correctly write my text to the file

```
Text<-"<!doctype html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head>
<meta charset=\"utf-8\">

<style>
body {
font-size : 16px;
font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
" 

fileConn<-file("mywebpage.html")
writeLines(Text, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Maybe that will help you.